# Acceptability of Code Reviews

Tags: discussion

Some tertiary StackExchange sites allow code reviews (Gavedev, for instance), though limited in scope. Some are more strict about policing this policy than others.

What should be our policy regarding code reviews? Given that Magento itself implements multiple ways of accomplishing similar tasks, should our SE site be a forum to discuss best practices via the reviewing of other's code?

I'm not advocating, just looking to start a discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think davidalger is right.

It doesn't provide valuable content and makes a lot of work. I don't think there will be lots of smart people after the tenth question who will explain you why

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->query($query);
```

is a really bad idea...

Comment: Would this not be closed as duplicate, then? I see what you're saying and this is probably a concrete example of the type of unavoidable pitfalls of allowing CR

Comment: no it will not be closed, because it is a code review :) Code reviews take a lot of time and it takes a lot of knowledge to do a good job with this. I want to sell this type of work :) I don't know how the other think about this.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Because you kill every help magento offers to prevent sql injection bigs

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I understand your argument, that this is a service you want to sell. How about giving some best practices advices? Cause I agree with this I think about deleting this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178640/ecg-compliance-how-to-do I planned to update it from time to time, but now ... Better delete it?

Comment: Oh no, I'm not against it. I'm for it! Really. What I don't want is hundreads of unanswered code review questions. And code reviews help 1 person, maybe a team. But most of the time not many :-/ The questions you posted is impressive. As long as it is fun, please do it!

Answer (score 2):

Opening questions for the purpose of discussing best-practices should be discouraged because it does not fit the Q&A format of this site and is not typically constructive unless limited to the experienced Magento developers. Giving advice on using best-practices in answers, comments, etc, etc; should be highly encouraged, but then recognized that if someone is offering a best-practice pointer that's not actually the case, it could be rebutted by a more experienced member if seen.

Comment: We have a chance to set the direction for our own community during the beta. Perhaps code reviews are constructive for many developers in the community because Magento is a complex beast. I tend to agree with you, but seeing the more focused SE communities starting to accept it in a limited fashion it makes me wonder if they're on to something.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no reason why you shouldn't submit your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ although there is no magento tag there yet. You would likely submit php code, so you will get some opinions there.

Comment: Thank you for that. This is now a 3 year old question and likely not relevant anymore.

Comment: @philwinkle I was about to submit a part of my module for review but stopped because of this question. I'll submit it on codereview.